# Backbone.js: trigger an event on a view after the render

Tags: jquery, view, backbone.js, coffeescript, render

Is there a way to bind an event to occur after the render is finished in a backbone view?

I'm trying to attach a jQuery Date Range Picker to an input which is appended to the DOM after a link is clicked, but if I do it during the render, the range picker appears in the wrong place (because the input hasn't been given a DOM position yet).  So, I need to wait until after the input has been rendered before I attach the date picker.  Coffeescript is below.

`@makeDateRangePicker` is a function that inits the date picker

```
class window.ClientDestinationPricingFieldsView extends ModelSaverView
  template: (json) ->
    _.template(jQuery("#special-pricing-timeframe-template").html()) json

  render: ->
    jQuery(@el).html @template(@model.toJSON())
    @makeDateRangePicker jQuery(@el).find("input[name=date_range]")
    this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

```
class window.ClientDestinationPricingFieldsView extends ModelSaverView
  events:
    'click input[name=date_range]': 'makeDateRangePicker'

  template: (json) ->
    _.template(jQuery("#special-pricing-timeframe-template").html()) json

  render: ->
    jQuery(@el).html @template(@model.toJSON())
    this
```

You would have to modify `@makeDateRangePicker` to take an event element instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** So, my last stab at a solution was not.

What you're saying is that after your call to `jQuery(@el).html`, the expected html is not there? That sounds very weird. I think it might be as simple as that you need to quote your attribute value:

```
jQuery(@el).find("input[name='date_range']")
```

Note the `'` single-quote around `date_range`.

**Edit:** Sorry, after verifying that it actually seems to work without quotes. I've been bitten by something similar before. Anyway, if the question is correct as it is now (after it's been updated with info about adding the input on a click event), then you should call `makeDateRangePicker` right after you append the element, right?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned in the question that this view is loaded after a click event from another element on the page, so waiting for document.ready won't fix it.

Comment: I figured as much after I had already answered. So you're saying that `input[name=` ... I think I've got it. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a timeout of zero for this sort of thing. `setTimeout(..., 0)` essentially queues up a function to be called once the browser has control again. Something like this:

```
render: ->
  jQuery(@el).html @template(@model.toJSON())
  setTimeout
    => @makeDateRangePicker jQuery(@el).find("input[name=date_range]")
    0
  @
```

I often use this trick with Google Maps to make it positioned and sized properly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to trigger a custom event from the parent view after rendering is complete. `$('body').trigger('my-rendering-is-done')` (a better way would be to trigger it on the view which is being rendered from the calling code). And have a listener in your view which uses the `makeDateRangePicker`.